# show errors in custom page rather than in default page while login/signup with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have put login and signup in one page and every thing works fine except when I encounter errors. Then the page redirects to their default pages and show errors there. In my case the login redirects me to the default domain.com/users/sign_in , but signup redirects me to domain.com/users.

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'visitor#index'

  namespace :admin do
    # get "/stats" => "stats#stats"
    devise_scope :admin_user do
      get '/stats/:scope' => 'stats#stats', as: :admin_stats
    end
  end

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  namespace :client do
    get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: 'dashboard'
    # resources :verification, only: [:create, :index, :destroy]
    get 'verification' => 'verification#index', as: 'verification'
    match 'verification' => 'verification#upload', as: 'verification_upload', via: [:post, :patch]
  end

  devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
  # devise_scope :user do
  #   root to: 'devise/registrations#new'
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `CustomFailure` class to control where the redirect goes if Devise fails to authenticate.

It's explained at this wiki page...

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated